# Should I use js or iframe for a widget?

Tags: javascript, iframe, widget

I don't know the advantages and disadvantages of using them.

I would like to know how they behave differently for

```
->cookies
->styling
->performance
->ease of use
->ease of implementation
->flexibility
->other pros/cons
->your preference
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Widget - Iframe versus JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535676/widget-iframe-versus-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would use JS.

**JS Pros:-**

- No cookie restriction. IE rejects iframe cookies if P3P headers are not set.
- No DOM access restriction. Interacting between JS codes in parent and iframe codes is not easy and needs workarounds. Not beautiful.
- Performance is not a big deal for JS on today's browsers.
- You get more flexibility here, because of first two points.

Which you feel is easier is debatable. I see no cons for JS.