# custom widget iframe or js+json or else?

Tags: javascript, iframe, widget

we will develop a widget that will contain news from users profile. and a couple of images like flickr.

I was wondering what are the keys points while developing a widget, which will be placed in users blogs and profile pages?

I saw couple of iframe solutions and a couple of json , js solutions ? which one is doing more effective and reliable.

or do you know any other options ?

Edit:
I found a previous discussion and a post but can I call inline js widgets evil ? and no one will use it ?

- [Widget - Iframe versus JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/535676/widget-iframe-versus-javascript)
- http://prettyprint.me/2009/05/30/widgets-iframe-vs-inline/