# Javascript for calling another js that creates a chatbox in your page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe, chat

I´m trying to make my chat system more "portable". What I want to do is give mi clients a pice of javascipt to put in their HTML that calls another JS that creates in their pages on the bottom right the chat widget.

This is the code I want to provide my clients to make the magic:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)){ return; }
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "js/js2.js";
        //js.async = true;
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'mitrol-jssdk'));
</script>
```

The problem is the following: I´m using the Angular Bootrstrap Simple Chat plugin that creates the chat, the problem is that I don´t know how to call all of the stuff (html, angular script, and my css and custom js) from the JS that I´m going to provide to my clients.

Any help on how to start?
Should I use an iframe to make my widget independent from the DOM of the page of my clients?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Hi Santiago, maybe what you are trying to accomplish it's not possible...what if in your client sites, your chat get conflict with their css or javascript routines making their site unworkable?...maybe you can try with an iframe and see how that works...just put in your client feet: do you think that their lead developer are going to permit that some dude inject javascript routines and css on their sites?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. As you mentioned, I think the way to do it is using an iframe to make my widget independent from all the css and js that my client uses. There is a competitor of us that is making it that way, they provide you that injection of the JS and in a div, they create an iframe with their chat

Comment: Just use an iframe, it is more secure....take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535676/widget-iframe-versus-javascript

Comment: Thank you very much, that was very helpfull